# Is there a way to debug a SPFX Outlook add in using VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, outlook-web-addins, spfx

The TypeScript code of new SPFX SharePoint web parts can be debugged in the context of SP using gulp serve. However I could not find if and how to debug an SP hosted SPFX Outlook add-in in the documentation. I am using VSCode.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you please share your exact requirement in a bit more details? In the meantime can you please check this link for debugging  SPFX solutions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/debug-in-vscode

Comment: How can I debug the TypeScript of an app like the one described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/office-addins-tutorial, using VSCode? I cannot use gulp serve and add it as a SP app for debugging, as described in your link for apps that run on a SP page, because it runs in the Outlook web client and uses its context. The best I currently can do is to debug the generated Javascript in the browser. Or is there another way?

Comment: The most robust way most often is to debug the generated javascript. However you can try this guide to Typescript debugging with VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging

Comment: Thank you or your efforts and references. However the answers are still not quite clear to me. Both descriptions for debugging a TypeScript app do depend on starting the browser environment with the app from VScode (using F5). The Outlook add-in however does only work in its Outlook context if it is first sideloaded, (Web-) Outlook is started, and the app is selected. Can I somehow define a workbench that will start Outlook from VSCode in a way that allows debugging the TypeScript app?

Comment: I think there are 2 parts here - 1. loading the webpart in Outlook addins with the code from gulp serve and 2. debug in VS code. For #1, use gulp package-solution (instead of --ship) similar to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page and the addin should be using your localhost gulp serve code for browser debugging.  For #2 here's some info for VS Code https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-with-vs-extension. This has not been tested with SPFx. I suggest trying #1 first with browser debugger.

Comment: Thank you. #1 is helpful in the sense that although the generated JavaScript is debugged instead of the Typescript, the original method- and variable names are preserved. Therefore the related TypeScript code can easily be found. I have also tried your suggestion at #2, but this add in 'Microsoft Office Add-in Debugger' depends on Edge (not Chromium). It doesn't seem trivial to return to this Edge version without getting behind on Windows updates. I hope a new version of this add in will become available.